# Java Spring Wizard Form + db query on every page

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to build a java webapp that has 3 pages, where each page has a drop down list with data that is fetched from db. Page 1 has a drop down box with possible value A and B, fetched from db. Page 1 drop down box value will be used as key to fetch the data for page 2 drop down list, and likewise Page 2 drop down box value will be used as key to fetch the data for page 3 drop down list.
I am thinking to use wizard form, where the chosen value of each page's drop down list value can be stored in a questionnaire object. My question is on how to make use of each page drop down list value to fetch data? May I get some direction here? Thanks. I am looking into several method like formbackingobject, referencedata that seems able to do the job.

Comment: It's good practice to press <kbd>Return</kbd> sometimes :)

Comment: Thanks RC, my first post here. I manage to add <br/>